# Signal between threads

Tags: java, .net, multithreading

This is an interview question in pseudo code.  I was told there are problems in the following approach.  I could not find anything else other than holding the main thread while the event is waiting.  Can you guys see any real issues?

Here is the question:

There is a main thread and a child thread.  The child thread is monitoring on a 30K message, which is sent in 1K chunks from an external source.  Once the child thread sees a 1K chunk ready, it signals the main thread function to retrieve the data.  The pseudo code is:

```
// This method is called in main thread

void MainThreadFunction(out message)
{   
    var buffer;

    loop
    {
        event.Wait;
            read data to buffer;
        event.Release;

        if (all the data of the message complete)
        {
            exit loop;
        }
    }

    copy buffer to message;
}

// This method is in child thread

void ChildThreadFunction()
{

    // once the 1K chunk of data is ready
    event.Set;
}
```

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, there's no point in using a child thread like this. As you wrote, the main process waits for the child to read 1K. It could as well read the 1K itself.

Answer (score 1):

The child thread does not wait for the main thread to read the data, so it can start overwriting it with new data before the old data is read.

Typically in this kind of situation, you maintain 2 or more buffers that the child thread can write into.  While the main thread is reading one, the child thread is writing the next.  When all the buffers are full, the child thread has to wait for the main thread to finish with one.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering